# LACP: Between RB750 and Huawei Ne20

Tags: ieee-802.1ax, huawei

I'm making a test to create a PORT AGGREGATION between my RB750 and Huawei NE20.

[image]

Rb750:

```
Flags: X - disabled, R - running 
 0  R name="bonding1" mtu=1500 mac-address=D4:CA:6D:1D:6F:66 arp=enabled 
      arp-timeout=auto slaves=ether1,ether2 mode=802.3ad primary=none 
      link-monitoring=mii arp-interval=100ms arp-ip-targets="" 
      mii-interval=100ms down-delay=0ms up-delay=0ms lacp-rate=30secs 
      transmit-hash-policy=layer-2-and-3 min-links=0
```

NE20:

```
Eth-Trunk1 current state : UP (ifindex: 73)
Line protocol current state : UP
Link quality grade : GOOD
Description:
Switch Port, PVID :  200, TPID : 8100(Hex), Hash arithmetic : According to flow, Maximal BW: 200Mbps, Current BW: 200Mbps, The Maximum Transmit Unit is 1500
Internet protocol processing : disabled
IP Sending Frames' Format is PKTFMT_ETHNT_2, Hardware address is 487b-6b4a-cc5c
Current system time: 2018-04-12 15:32:33
Physical is ETH_TRUNK
    Last 300 seconds input rate 111 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
    Last 300 seconds output rate 5291 bits/sec, 8 packets/sec
    Input: 15012450 packets,22684847541 bytes
           14971431 unicast,30620 broadcast,10399 multicast
           10 errors,0 drops
    Output:795001 packets,252032412 bytes
           170137 unicast,540101 broadcast,84763 multicast
           0 errors,0 drops
    Last 300 seconds input utility rate:  0.01%
    Last 300 seconds output utility rate: 0.01%
----------------------------------------------------------
PortName                      Status              Weight
----------------------------------------------------------
GigabitEthernet0/3/28         UP                  1
GigabitEthernet0/3/29         UP                  1
----------------------------------------------------------
The Number of Ports in Trunk : 2
The Number of UP Ports in Trunk : 2
```

Well, apparently I got to establish a connection between them, another configuration were done.

VLAN 200 set in Eth-Trunk:

```
   #
    interface Eth-Trunk1
     portswitch
     port link-type access
     port default vlan 200
     mode lacp-static
    #
```

VLAN 200 set in bonding interface in Rb750

```
 #    NAME                   MTU ARP             VLAN-ID INTERFACE               
 0 R  VLAN-200              1500 enabled             200 bonding1
```

Using a BTest I got this result. You can realize the traffic is comming to one interface.

```
                         name:  ether1   ether2 bonding1
        rx-packets-per-second:       1       14       15
           rx-bits-per-second:  480bps  8.5kbps  9.0kbps
     fp-rx-packets-per-second:       1       11        6
        fp-rx-bits-per-second:  480bps  5.9kbps  3.8kbps
          rx-drops-per-second:       0        0        0
         rx-errors-per-second:       0        0        0
        tx-packets-per-second:       0    8 191    8 191
           tx-bits-per-second:    0bps 99.4Mbps 99.4Mbps
     fp-tx-packets-per-second:       0    8 171        0
        fp-tx-bits-per-second:    0bps 98.9Mbps     0bps
          tx-drops-per-second:       0        0        0
    tx-queue-drops-per-second:       0      882        0
         tx-errors-per-second:       0        0        0
-- [Q quit|D dump|C-z pause]
```

Note: I intent to deploy this using CCR1036 - Ne20, establishing 2GB. Rb750 is just to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you tested. You need to aware that any single flow will only use one of the port combinations each way. Port aggregation allows you to increase the throughput *for multiple flows, not for a single flow*.

How flows are distributed to the potential egress ports depends on the device. Most use either source/destination MAC addresses, source/destination IP addresses, or source/destination IP addresses and port numbers (SA/DA MAC, IP or IP/port). It's completely normal to have one direction of a flow to use a different port combination than the other.

Comment: The test that I'm doing, it have the purpose to eliminate some bottleneck in my CCR1036. `ETHER1 - LINK (1GB)`. The Sum of traffic from `Eth2,Eth3` is more than 1Gb, so in this case, the Port aggregation will work, because this is multiple flows?

Comment: Aggregation *might* work. The SA/DA distribution method discussed above doesn't guarantee an optimal load balancing - it's rather random (unless optimized). You can improve the chances by using more than two links.

Comment: I sent the traffic from two `CCRs` and apparently used 200mb

Comment: Quite possible with IP/port SA/DA and multiple connections. But I didn't actually get that until now - *Fast* Ethernet? Seriously?

Comment: Sorry, but what is SA/DA? I don't know what you didn't understand but both devices that I need to establish the port aggregation are GbE.

Comment: SA/DA is short for source address/destination address traffic distribution. Look at your posted data, it shows 100 Mbit/s links.

Comment: hmm, but I mentioned that I'm using Rb750 just to test LACP, but my intention is establish 2Gb :)